# PHP the difference between 2 type of dependency injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, logic, difference

I’d like to ask you for an opinion on things

What is the deficiency between  2 addictive injection method?
 I explain to you the code:

the first is to inject the Class to be used in the manufacturer:

```
/**
     * @var FileUploader
     */
    private FileUploader $fileUploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        $this->fileUploader = $fileUploader;
    }
```

the second way is to inject directly into the function:

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="admin_images_index", methods={"GET"})
     * @param ImagesRepository $imagesRepository
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(ImagesRepository $imagesRepository): Response
    {
        $query = $imagesRepository->findByImage();

        return $this->render('images/index.html.twig', [
            'images' => $query,
        ]);
    }
```

So my question is this:

What is the difference between this 2 ways of doing things? Which one should one choose? Which one should be the most efficient? Or is it just 2 styles to do?

If anyone who knows the answer to my question could answer that would be really nice,

thank you very much for your future answer and good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Difference is the structure of your class. If you want to use more then in one function the injecting object you must use first for pretty code. If you want to use only in one function you must use second, because you must to think about load and what will do that class.

### Updated

*The "load" mean:*

Then you make injection into the constructor, it will put all data into ram and waiting for use it (for faster processing), so let's thing if that your injection is very big object (large bits amount placed into ram and slow load it), so your script will make respond longer, for everything what you code process. Then you will use more then in one class that for ex. large object, then you can inject it to constructor, anyway you will not pointless code if it will be use right.

**Summary:**

There is not very difference, if it only once using or small parts. But if you make have all your's code heavy, so your load will be same slowly.

*Make your code light and easy to use your self and computer.*

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer. What do you mean by "you must think about load"?